# Inefficiency of the code

Tags: java, big-o

I have the code here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class AddElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
          a.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(a);
        // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        addElementAtBeginning(a, -1, 4);
        System.out.println(a);
        // [-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    

       addElementAtBeginning(a, -2, 7);
        System.out.println(a);
        // [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }

    public static <T> void addElementInBeginning1(ArrayList<T> a, T fillElem, int nFills){
          for(int fills=0; fills<nFills; fills++){
               a.add(fillElem);
               for(int i=a.size()-1; i>0; i--){
               a.set(i, a.get(i-1));
          }
          a.set(0, fillElem);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void addElementAtBeginning2(ArrayList<T> a, T fillElem, int nfills){
        for(int i = 0; i < nfills; i++){
            a.add(0, fillElem);
        }
    }
}
```

Both of the methods produce the same result. The problem is in their efficiency.
I just want to make sure that the first method, `addElementAtBeginning1()`, takes `O(N^2)` and `addElementAtBeginning2()` takes `O(N)`. Am I correct?

Comment: @HyperZ I think it is beneficial to separate the number of elements in the array list and `nfills` for the analysis, because the two numbers could be of different orders of magnitude.

Comment: @John, why do you constantly delete your code? Your question without your code is meaningless. If you for some reason want to remove it, then remove the whole question (there's a "delete" link at the bottom of the question). If your account is taken over by malicious user, please [contact](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) site moderators.

Comment: @TagirValeev, I constantly delete the code because some of the question are based on my project and others from the same school might copy the whole code which puts me in a bad position. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect: both your methods take O(F * (N+F)) time, where `N` is the number of elements in the list, and F is your `nFills` variable.

The reason `addElementInBeginning1` takes O(F *(N+F)) is simple: it has two nested loops, one on `nFills` and the other one on `N`, with the nested loop performing O(1) operations. The size of the array list at the end of the operation is `N+F`.

The reason `addElementInBeginning2` takes O(F *(N+F)) is dependent on the data structure used in the implementation: each iteration of the loop that executes `nFills` times takes time dependent on the data structure. For `ArrayList` the time of inserting at zero is O(N). For a linked list the time is O(1), so the overall time with a linked list would have been O(F).

Comment: I have two questions:1) When does the size at the end of the operation is N+F? At what line? 2)Why does LinkedList take O(1)?

Comment: @John You start an array list with N elements, then you add F elements to it, so upon completion of your method the size of the array list is N+F. In your example, you start with five, add four, and end up with nine. Linked list takes O(1) to insert at the beginning of the list because it does not make a copy of the node chain following the head node. Array list, on the other hand, needs to copy all N elements, so insertion is O(N).